# Разбор JSON, полученного от сервера

Tags: python, json

Есть данные с веб-адреса http://195.69.67.21:151/status.json,
не могу запихнуть их в json.

```
import urllib.request
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://195.69.67.21:151/status.json')

#print(list(response))
j1=json.loads(str(response), skipkeys=False)
```

То ли сначала надо почистить  от \r\n,  но, по идее, если в специфике железки стоит, что она отдаёт по запросу json, то всё должно быть нормально, а тут не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = response.read().decode()

j1 = json.loads(string)
```

Comment: Интересно, а почему метод .decode()  убирает \r\n,  в описании не нашёл
или это из библиотеки json?

Comment: По соединению передаётся строка байтов, метод decode преобразует её в просто строку.

import urllib.request
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://195.69.67.21:151/status.json')
b = response.read()
print(type(b))  # <class 'bytes'>
s = b.decode()
print(type(s))  # <class 'str'>